# Avoiding multiple (not nested) if statements in my code

Tags: python, if-statement

I am writing a function to scan a specific map (2D array). In order to avoid scanning spots outside of the array, I wrote a few if statements, but it feels like the wrong, long, inefficient way of doing it.

H is the map's height value, int
W is for width, int
c is the current spot, a tuple containing x and y values.

```
    floorH = c[0]-D
    floorW = c[1]-D
    ceilingH = c[0]+D+1
    ceilingW = c[1]+D+1
    if floorH < 0:
        floorH = 0
    if floorW < 0:
        floorW = 0
    if ceilingH > H:
        ceilingH = H
    if ceilingW > W:
        ceilingW = W
```

How can I write this better?

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Instead of using conditionals you could just use the max and min functions.

```
floorH = c[0]-D
floorW = c[1]-D
ceilingH = c[0]+D+1
ceilingW = c[1]+D+1
floorH  = max(floorH, 0)
floorW  = max(floorW, 0)
ceilingH = min(ceilingH , H)
ceilingW = min(ceilingW , W)
```

Actually you can make it even shorter:

```
floorH  = max(c[0]-D, 0)
floorW  = max(c[1]-D, 0)
ceilingH = min(c[0]+D+1, H)
ceilingW = min(c[1]+D+1, W)
```

Comment: This is the one I use.
My teammates and I find it easier to read and less prone to boundary errors.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You can format your `if` like this to save space:

```
floorH = c[0]-D if c[0]-D > 0 else 0
floorW = c[1]-D if c[1]-D > 0 else 0
ceilingH = c[0]+D+1 if c[0]+D+1 < H else H
ceilingW = c[1]+D+1 if c[1]+D+1 < W else W
```